# Is there a way to track robocopy's progress

Tags: python, tkinter, subprocess, robocopy

I have made a progress bar with tkinter. I am trying to let the progress bar follow the copying progress. Is there a way to see the progress of robocopy and use that for the progress bar?

I know have some sort of a solution by calculating the size of the source directory and then checking the size of the destination directory. It does work, but I can't check if anything is skipped by robocopy and then the progress bar will go on forever.

I use this code for robocopy:

```
subprocess.call(["robocopy", os.path.dirname(file_path), new_destination, filename[0], "/V", "/ETA", "/W:3", "/R:3",
                          "/TEE", "/LOG+:" +
                          new_destination + "copy.log"])
```

I want to update the progress bar with the progress from the robocopy output if this is possible and if that is not possible, a way to check if robocopy is finished.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm afraid you'll need to split between copying a large amount of files, and monitor the progress, based on the number of copied files, and copying one very large file, based on the number of already copied (kilo/Mega)bytes.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I have figured out a way to track the progress. Maybe it is not the best way, but it is good enough for my use. Please see my answer how I did it. Thanks that you took the time to look and respond to my question.

Answer (score 0):

First When i press a button and have selected the files/directories that I want to copy, I check what size it is all combined. I save that and set the maximum value of the progress bar to the total size. Then the start_calc method is executed.

```
for item in self.file_and_directory_list:
            folder = ""
            my_file = ""
            if os.path.isdir(item):
                folder = item
            else:
                my_file = item

            if folder != "":
                print("folder")
                for (path, dirs, files) in os.walk(folder):
                    for file in files:
                        filename = os.path.join(path, file)
                        folder_size += os.path.getsize(filename)
            else:
                folder_size += os.path.getsize(item)

        if os.path.exists(new_destination):
            for (path, dirs, files) in os.walk(new_destination):
                for file in files:
                    filename = os.path.join(path, file)
                    folder_size += os.path.getsize(filename)

        processing_bar_copy_files["maximum"] = folder_size

        processing_bar_copy_files["value"] = 0

        threading.Thread(target=self.start_calc, args=(folder_size, new_destination)).start()
```

The start_calc method where I calculate the size of the destination directory and check if it is smaller compared to the source directory. If it is smaller the value of the progress bar is set to the size of destination directory:

```
def start_calc(self, source_folder_size, new_destination):
    folder = new_destination
    dest_folder_size = 0

    try:
        for (path, dirs, files) in os.walk(folder):
            for file in files:
                filename = os.path.join(path, file)
                dest_folder_size += os.path.getsize(filename)
    except Exception as error:
        tkinter.messagebox.showerror(f"Er is iets fout gegaan:\n{error}")
    finally:
        if processing_bar_copy_files["value"] < processing_bar_copy_files["maximum"]:
            processing_bar_copy_files["value"] = dest_folder_size
            progress_percentage = (processing_bar_copy_files["value"] / processing_bar_copy_files["maximum"]) * 100
            progress_text_var.set(str("{:.1f}".format(progress_percentage) + "%"))
            self.size = dest_folder_size
            window.after(500, self.start_calc, source_folder_size, new_destination)
```

If the copying of the files is completed, the progress bar is removed and stopped and the button is placed back.